# Weird hidden folder in D drive

Tags: windows

I have this following weird folders named "Cstores242" and "Tlogs24" appearing in my D drive.
When I delete it, it recreates itself with different name.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use Sysinternals Process Monitor to find out which program creates them. Start monitoring, delete it, stop monitor. You could also export the trace but be aware that it *may* contain sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB, I saw what was causing the issue using Process Monitor. Issue resolved.

Comment: It's usually a virus.

Comment: @tony9099 could you self post an answer to what it was to close the loop?

Comment: Answer posted below as suggested by @JourneymanGeek

Answer (score 5):

After I got suggested to use Sysinternals to monitor the process, it turned out that a newly installed `anti ransomware` from https://ransomfree.cybereason.com/ was causing the issue (if its an issue in the first place)

Uninstalling the software fixed the issue.

Apparently, these are files created as "Honeypots" where the software uses them as a reference to see if anything is being altered or encrypted.

Comment: Ah, it was perhaps intended as a “sensor” of sorts, to detect when files get encrypted.

Comment: yes @DanielB most probably. Freaked me out for around half an hour tho :)